# Как осуществить прямой доступ к пикселям изображения, не используя Bitmap ?

Tags: c#, .net

Как осуществить прямой доступ к пикселям изображения, не используя Bitmap ?

Comment: А чем не устраивает Bitmap?

Comment: Имеется ввиду работа с графикой без использования GDI+ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BitmapData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.aspx)

а также можно посмотреть одну из перегрузок конструктора `Bitmap` где есть `IntPtr` в конце списка аргументов.

Answer (score 1):

[Есть ли в WPF эффективный метод что бы рисовать графику на пиксельном уровне?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/fordesktopru/thread/b8258fb0-c849-47ac-aa6d-a48344cc6fa4)